# How to configure virtualenv path?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I'm using pyenv, so everything is under .pyenv like this: [image]. I tried to use `virtualenv` that I installed before, but it keeps trying to find `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/virtualenv` which leads to errors. How do i configure virtualenv so it's using python in my pyenv?

Thanks!